# How to signify swiping to access a menu?

Tags: actions, signifier

So I'm designing a notes app for iPhone and I've hit some trouble. I can't figure out how to signify swiping to access more actions. Similar to what Mailbox does (see image below) however there will be multiple actions underneath. I really don't want to use tutorials to teach the user this action and was hopping you guys might know of a signifier I could use?

[image: Mailbox swiping feature]

Comment: As an inherently difficult interaction to discover and a difficult one to execute for people with certain kinds of impairment, make sure these gestures are not the only way to trigger these actions (that way if users don't discover these functions they're still able to perform the action albeit in a more convoluted way). That's how Apple does it in Mail (for example).

Answer (score 1):

You could point the chevron inwards to indicate that the user has the ability to swipe for something more. Only problem is you'd have to have it on all your cells, which you may not prefer...

Another idea is that when a "note" is made, you animate the note cell sliding over the options, to rest. That would give the user a glimpse of the options that lay beneath.

Comment: I like the second idea but shouldn't the user be taken straight to the note when they press the "New Note" button? How are you visualizing the "new note" animation that would allow the user to get a glimpse of the options beneath it without interrupting the flow of creating a new note?

Comment: Perhaps you could show the animation after the user is done editing the note?

Comment: Sorry to reply so late... But absolutely, if you still would like my confirmation. After the user finishes theiry note, you would create some animation in which the "note cell" slides over all of the options. After a while, if not right at first, the user would hopefully catch on.

Answer (score 0):

How about if someone taps+holds, it has a bounce/peek animation (like when someone taps on the camera icon on the lock screen in iOS)

Comment: Welcome to ux.stackexchange. This interaction sometimes can be a good alternative to swiping but it seems even harder to signify that there is this kind of interaction to access the menu. Please go into more detail in your answer and give an example for the interaction indicator / explain why no indicator is needed :)

Comment: @Marvin You know how on the ios lock screen, the camera icon has an animation to bounce when tapped, signifying that you can swipe up? What if tapping the note (for a longer than normal tap) causes the same animation, to signify that one can swipe the note?

Comment: Daniel, I understand what you are saying. However, a tap on a note would open the note and signifying for a long tap would be more challenging than signifying to swipe.

Comment: Maybe after 15 seconds of inactivity, a hint/tip could pop up? I wouldn't consider that a tutorial exactly.